# java.nio: Constructing BigInteger from ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio

I need to deserialize `BigInteger` instances from byte buffers and do it fast. The combination of `new BigInteger(byte[], int, int)` and `ByteBuffer#array()` seems to be the best option, but it only works with heap buffers.

With direct and mapped buffers, I would need to create a temporary byte array, pass it to the constructor, which will convert the array into its internal `int[]` representation, and eventually discard the byte array I just created - clearly a waste of resources.

Byte buffers and **java.nio** have been around for ages. Are there any reasons why there's no `new BigInteger(ByteBuffer, int, int)` constructor? Which, looking at the sources, should be a few minutes job.

Comment: Perhaps this enhancement hasn't occurred to the developers (not unreasonable, considering all the other stuff they have to focus on). You could submit an enhancement request (I couldn't find an existing one). Note I believe such a constructor would only need a `ByteBuffer` argument, since that class already encapsulates the offset and length via its "position" and "limit" properties.

Comment: @Slaw, thanks, could you please share the link to the enhancement requests/submission form?

Comment: https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/